# redirection problems in csh

Tags: shell, grep, csh

When I try to grep pattern and write to a file, sometimes it complains the file bar.txt already exist, so I have to use `>>` instead of `>` to overwrite it.

```
grep 'pattern' foo.txt >> bar.txt
```

But if the file didn't exist, using `>>` it will complain about no such file or directory. Is there a way for shell to automatically make it's own decision? If not exist, create a file. If exists, overwrite.

Comment: `>>` doesn't overwrite; either you're confused about what `>>` does, or you're confused about what "overwrite" means.

Comment: Also, according to http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html, `>` will not complain that a file already exists unless you've set the `noclobber` option, and `>>` will *never* complain that a file doesn't already exist. Are you sure you're actually using Bash?

Comment: I am using csh @ruakh

Comment: Maybe try it with [`tee`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29)? Also, why did you tag this with [tag:bash]?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Sorry about the confusion, I shouldn't tag Bash. The issues I stated is with csh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extracted from the [tcsh man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tcsh):

```
   > name
           ...
           If the shell variable noclobber is set, then the file must  not
           exist  or  be  a  character  special  file (e.g., a terminal or
           `/dev/null') or an error results.  This helps prevent  acciden-
           tal  destruction  of  files.
           ...


   >> name
           ...
           Like `>', but appends output to the end of name.  If the  shell
           variable noclobber is set, then it is an error for the file not
           to exist, unless one of the `!' forms is given.
```

So ... it sounds to me as if you have "noclobber" set.

```
% set noclobber
% echo foo >> bar
bar: No such file or directory.
% echo foo > bar
% echo foo > bar
bar: File exists.
% unset noclobber
% echo foo > bar
```

If this special shell variable was set in your `.tcshrc` or `.cshrc` or `.login`, you can unset it. Or, if it is on by default or set in a system-wide shell startup file, simply append a line to your rc file:

```
unset noclobber
```

And you should be good to go.

Comment: You're very welcome. If this solved your problem, please feel free to click the green arrow on the left-hand side of the answer in order to mark your question as resolved.

Comment: You can also overwrite `noclobber` by using `>!`, and for very new versions of tcsh (Sept 2015 and later) you can use `set noclobber = ask`.